# How to see exactly what line of code is covered by that test? Java JUnit

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, junit

For a legacy project there are many tests. Maybe a bit too many. So I want to clean it up. This is why I need to know what test, tests which lines. So I can map out which lines are tested multiple times.

Do you know a way/script that can do that?

Comment: Run Unit Test class with coverage

Comment: can you help me understand the reason behind knowing lines which are tested multiple times? why do you want clean up test case, as it is generally good to have as diverse test-cases possible.

Comment: @surajs1n We currently have over 400 tests on one microservice. It takes currently around 8 minutes to run it locally and over 15 minutes to run them in the pipeline. This is just too long. We assume that quite a big part of those tests test the same. So we want to see what the overlap or duplication is.

Comment: You can explore the possibility of running some of them parallel. One of the teams in my previous company had done the same thing. Their test suite use to run over an hr. They had 1000+ test cases. After optimisation they brought it down to 15mins. Again, please feel free to diff with my points.

Comment: @Pawan.Java This shows the percentage, but not exactly which lines are covered by which test or visa versa which test cover which lines